Discrepancies Between GitHub API and Web Interface Search Results
I am currently facing issues with the GitHub Search API where the number of search results significantly differs from what I see on the GitHub web app. I would like to understand these discrepancies and find a solution.
ISSUE 1 ⚠️ Discrepancy in Search Results Count
Question❓ Why there's a large discrepancy between the API and web interface results?
Query Used:
"new(params[" OR "create(params[" OR "update_attributes(params[" path:app/controllers language:Ruby

URL: https://github.com/search?q=%22new%28params%5B%22+OR+%22create%28params%5B%22+OR+%22update_attributes%28params%5B%22+path%3Aapp%2Fcontrollers+language%3ARuby&type=code&p=1
Expected Behavior:
When I run this search query on the GitHub website, it shows approximately 123k results.And it should also show same results for Github code search API.
Actual Behavior:
Using the same query with the GitHub Search API returns only 225 results.
Additional Attempts:

I have tried encoding the query parameters too.
Here are the headers I am using: Authorization: Bearer token (Used GitHub personal access token), Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json, X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28.

Tried passing query parameters like these too:

https://api.github.com/search/code?q="new(params[" OR "create(params[" OR "update_attributes(params[" path:app/controllers language:Ruby&per_page=100
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=%22new%28params%5B%22%20OR%20%22create%28params%5B%22%20OR%20%22update_attributes%28params%5B%22%20path%3Aapp/controllers%20language%3ARuby&per_page=100
https://api.github.com/search/code?q="new%28params%5B"+OR+"create%28params%5B"+OR+"update_attributes%28params%5B"+path%3Aapp%2Fcontrollers+language%3ARuby&per_page=100
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=%22new%28params%5B%22+OR+%22create%28params%5B%22+OR+%22update_attributes%28params%5B%22+path%3Aapp%2Fcontrollers+language%3ARuby&per_page=100

ISSUE 2 ⚠️ Navigation Limit on GitHub Web Interface
Question❓ Is there a limitation on how many pages or results one can navigate through on the GitHub website? If so, then why?
Description:
While the GitHub web interface initially shows 123k files for the above query, it does not allow navigating beyond the 5th page of results.
Expected Behavior:
When I run this search query on the GitHub website, it shows approximately 123k results.And it should also show same results for @Github code search API.

For your first issue, GitHub web search and Search Code API rely on different "engines", so the total counts returned can often be different. According to this reply from GitHub's staff to a similar question on GitHub:

Unfortunately the new web search uses Blackbird (more details in this post), and because of changes to the search syntax and search results we have not yet upgraded the REST API to use this engine.

For your second issue, GitHub web search UI's current limit is 100 results. There are 20 results per page, so the limit is 5 pages to browse per the official documentation.

Results for any search with code search are restricted to 100 results (5 pages). Sorting is not supported for code search results at this time. This limitation only applies to searching code with the new code search and does not apply to other types of searches.

Per this reply from another GitHub staff to another discussion thread, they plan to allow searching without the 100 result limit, but there are no further details yet at this moment.
